# Laravel collection manipulation

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have `User` model that has 2 fields: `email` and `id`
I have this query:

```
$users = User::all()->get();
```

the result will be 3 User objects in a Collection
I want to see the result as the following:

```
[87 => 'user@gmail.com', 92 => 'admin@gmail.com', 10 => 'super@gmail.com']
```

id will be the key and email will be the value.
Is that possible via Collection class to implement? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$users = User::pluck('email','id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve like this,

```
$users = User::pluck("email","id");
```

`pluck()` -> You may also specify how you wish the resulting collection to be keyed:

There is alternative to do this(playing with collections),

```
$users = User::all()->get();
$users = $users->pluck("email","id");
```

Give it a try, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
$users = User::all();
$data = array();
foreach ($users as $key) {
    $data[$key->id] = $key->email;
}
print_r($data);
```

Good luck...